# JSON.stringify does not work in IE

Tags: json, internet-explorer

I have used the following method:

```
JSON.stringify(json,null,2);
```

This produces tabbed output in all browsers except IE: in IE, it displays a single line. Is `null` the problem and if so what are the alternatives?

Comment: What version of IE are you using? `stringify` is supported from IE8 upwards: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/10/native-json-in-ie8.aspx

Comment: What my viewers use is more to the point. I have tested it in IE7.

Answer (score 5):

You Can use jquery.min.js or latest or 1.8.2 version and put this in the `<head>` element:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

It works in IE8 and above.

Answer (score 3):

Ok.. This might not be the solution to your problem exactly but might help others coming here:

Yes, as Lycha mentioned, this is supported in IE8 and above.

So, if you are still getting a "JSON undefined" error, it must be a "DOCTYPE" problem.

Hence, mention the proper DOCTYPE (and preferably keep your document in valid xhtml format (i.e. , ,  tags etc)..) and things should work fine.

Not mentioning (proper) DOCTYPE generally creates a LOT of issues with CSS in IE, and in this case JSON too.

--

(IE === 'bad')

Comment: Thanks, adding a correct DOCTYPE did the trick for me. Just saved me an hour of googling... ;) +1

Answer (score 3):

One correct doctype for IE8 to support it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459%28VS.85%29.aspx), it looks like Internet Explorer expects either a function or an object for the second argument, otherwise it throws an exception.

You could try to use `undefined` instead of `null`. For example:

```
JSON.stringify(json,undefined,2)
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that. I think I might just have to spin out line by line with \t, \n, \r - quite horrible!

Comment: You don't have to add the third parameter, just undefined is adequate :) .. Thanks for this great hint !

Answer (score 2):

There may be situations where it may not be possible to include the Doctype or meta tag or nothing might work as in my case so I had to figure out this way below as explained.

To post json objects back to the server, json.strinfy will have to be supported. To support the same on IE, please download json2.js from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js and refer in your view. The following code snipped worked for me, I hope it helpe someone else too.

```
//include jquery library from your preferred cdn or local drive.
<!-- include json2.js only when you need JSON.stringfy method -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function button_click() {
 //object to post back to the server.
 var postData = { "Id": $('#hfUserId').val(), "Name": $('#Name').text(), 
 "address": new Array() };
 var address = new Array(); var addr;
 addr = { "HouseNo": "1", "Street": "ABC", "City": "Chicago", "State": "IL" };
 address[0] = addr;
 addr = { "HouseNo": "2", "Street": "DEF", "City": "Hoffman Est", "State": "IL" };
 address[1] = addr;
//make ajax call to server to save the data
 $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("myAction", "MyController")',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    async: true,
    success: function (data) { alert('User Saved'); },
    error: function (data) { alert('Could not save User'); }
    });
}
</script>
```

The model for the address list will be as below. Please note that the property names are the same as the addr object and it has get and set.

```
public class Address
{
    public string HouseNo { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

The controller action will be something like below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myAction(string Id, string Name, List<Address> address)
{
   JsonResult result = null;
   result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = new
                    {
                        error = false,
                        message = "User Saved !"
                    }
                };
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Great and smart Answer. You are right there will be situation where we cannot add Doctype or meta tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```