# Jquery ajax Delete not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

this is the below code which i am using for delete functionality.At Server side there is RestAPICall. But i can see the request is not at all going to back-end and neither i am getting any error in IE.It's working in FF,Chrome but not in IE9.

```
var delURL = "url call to restful webservices";
$.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url:delURL,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: sendUserData(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("inside error method->" + data);
        }
    });

var sendUserData = function(){
      return JSON.stringify(userData);               
    };
```

Everytime when i am trying to delete some records there is no request is going to back-end, instead immediately the alert statement in error method will get executed.
I had tried and googled some blogs. But not able to get the solution.

Before marking duplicate Let me list down what all i tried:-

1.IE does not support JSON object (e.g.: JSON.stringify()) but the json2.js plugin should compensate for that, and I see that is included in my code.  So I have not found the answer yet why still not working.

[JSON.stringify and JSON.parse not working in IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146268/json-stringify-and-json-parse-not-working-in-ie9)

[JSON.stringify does not work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150984/json-stringify-does-not-work-in-ie)

2.I also read that Jquery.Ajax with delete method not working in IE.

[Problem with jQuery.ajax with 'delete' method in ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456820/problem-with-jquery-ajax-with-delete-method-in-ie)